# import sybase data to sql server when any change make in table

Tags: sql-server, sybase

I have a `Sybase` database which i want to migrate to `SQL SERVER 2008R2`. I have done this, but i got a new requirement. When any data is modified or new insert in table in `Sybase` that data only  migrate from `Sybase` to `Sql Server`. The one table data is around 11,000135 so every time this is not possible to migrate all the data from Sybase to Sql Server. Is any possible way to do this?

Comment: If you don't need to resend all data, make some parts like daily parts by filtering a date field and so...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any straight forward solution here. I would use following steps to deal with that issue:

1. Create table with unique key of `source_table`:

   ```
   Create table mod_date
   (
      key int unique,
      modified_date datetime
   )
   ```
2. Create insert/update trigger for source_table that will be inserting/updating `modified_date` table.
3. When selecting data from `source_table` join `mod_date` and filter out only dates grater than last update.

Opposite to create new table yuo could also add `modified_date` to your `source_table` and use it during select. GL!